# Select statement written using statement.executeQuery can't select values having - (dash)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a Oracle database table `MyTable` that has a column `XYZ` with datatype `varchar2(40 Byte)`.

Also there is a row in that table having `XYZ` column's value like `'12345678-1234'`

When I use Oracle SQL client and run select statement: `select * from MyTable where XYZ='12345678-1234';`, it returns **one** record.

But when I execute same select statement using java (given below), it returns **no** rows.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);//I have proper parameters here
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
String query= "select * from MyTable where XYZ='12345678-1234'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs.next()){
 System.out.println(rs.getString("XYZ")); 
}else {
 System.out.println("No Value")); 
}
```

Here it always prints **No Value**

**EDIT:** when I use values which are without dash in table rows(for example: '12345678') then both of above gives same result- one row.

Please point out what I am missing here.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock: He already mentioned that the query is returning the row on the Oracle SQL client.

Comment: He said it returns data on the oracle client. Does "Select * from MyTable" return data? If the queries between your Oracle client and your Java client are identical, then it's likely that the connection info differs between the two.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock: I agree with you; OP needs to verify that the connection info don't differ.

Comment: CONNECTION INFO IS SAME. I checked many times. and please see edit.

Comment: You may need to escape the dash character. Try something like:  select * from MyTable where XYZ='12345678\-1234' escape '\'

Comment: did that before posting this question . didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock There is no reason in either Java or Oracle SQL to escape the `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from MyTable where XYZ = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "12345678-1234");
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I will try this and come back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was not a problem of java code I found.

**COMMIT was a culprit.**

I was accessing database from Oracle Sql client and Java simultaneously and that was causing above problem.

Then I used **Commit;** after each statement I execute in Oracle Sql client. *Then problem disappeared.*

If anyone wants to add some technical details to this then they are most welcome!

Comment: If you added the data in SQL Client, then it only becomes visible to other sessions if you commit the data. That is what transactions do.

Comment: That's the part I was overlooking.. Transactionss.... Thanks @MarkRotteveel